# Can I use a comma before "and" to show information at the end of a sentence only applies to the latter subject?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

Take this sentence:

> It applies to EU institutions and national governments when implementing EU law

The 'when implementing EU law' could be interpreted as being the case for both subjects (EU institutions and national governments) - which is not the case. To make it clear this only applies to the latter subject (national governments), I could swap the subjects around. However, could an alternative be to use a comma?

For example: It applies to EU institutions, and national governments when implementing EU law

Comment: The reader knows that EU would implement EU law. Here's how a comma can help: "EU institutions, and **to** national governments (when) implementing EU law."